# Smart contract call

Tags: wallets

If I accept a smart contract call on my Trust wallet app and it is malicious smart contact, can it risk other wallet on my app or just the one which accepted it? how deep it can reach?..wallet level/app level/phone level?

Sorry if it is stupid question but I'm new to this and it worry me a lot